# Drools - Kie Spring Integration - Interfaces

Tags: drools, business-process-management, kie, drools-flow

I am a newbie to Drools, Need some clarificatoins on Drools - Spring Integration.

```
 public KieFileSystem kieFileSystem() throws IOException {
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = getKieServices().newKieFileSystem();
    for (Resource file : getRuleFiles()) {
        kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(RULES_PATH + file.getFilename(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return kieFileSystem;
}

public KieContainer kieContainer() throws IOException {
    final KieRepository kieRepository = getKieServices().getRepository();


    kieRepository.addKieModule(new KieModule() {
        public ReleaseId getReleaseId() {
            return kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
        }
    });

    KieBuilder kieBuilder = getKieServices().newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem());
    kieBuilder.buildAll();

    return getKieServices().newKieContainer(kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
}
```

My understaing as per the documentation & few examples

1. We need to define rules in a file
2. KieFileSystem loads the rules into KieBuilder
3. KieBuilder holds the knowledge base
4. Based on KieBuilder we can prepare KieContainer & new KieSession
5. On KieSessoin we include the facts and fire the rules.

Question 1: What is the importance of KieModule, KieRepository, ReleaseId?

Question 2: I have seperate directories for different flows. How can I load specific rules based on flow?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "Spring Integration", but the `spring-integration` is indeed not what you have shown us: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-integration

Comment: I mean spring integration with drools, do not find the tag spring-drools.

Comment: You can create one or just use `drools` and `Spring` as a combination, but it is definitely wrong to abuse tag for fully different purpose